# Azure microsoft bot framework. Deployment(vs code) web.config file not found issue

Tags: node.js, azure, web-config, botframework, azure-bot-service

this qs is regarding Azure microsoft bot framework. I have created a nodejs bot , V4 having both luis, qna. Till last week it was working fine when deployed with changes via VS code. From this week, whenever i am trying to deploy my bot, i am facing issue to connect to my bot in web chat. 
1) web.config file is not created.
2) api/ messages url when trying to access gives resource not found.
3) in web chat gives error http 500.

My application id and application key is specified same in both .env file and connection string.
I don't know why i am not able to connect to my bot. Microsoft doc says if this is encountered redeploy again. I have redeployed many times , still facing the same error. Any help would be appreciated, how to backtrack . What to do?? What to check.??

Comment: was the bot working as expected locally(on the emulator) before you deploy the bot?

Comment: Yes it is working fine in emulator

Comment: Can you double-check the deployment steps? Are the changes getting reflected when you check in the online code editor?

Comment: as it was not deploying. i added web.config file manually and deployed it is working fine now. But before the web.config file was generating automatically when I was deploying.1) Is it right to add web.config maunally  and deploy??   2) Answer tp your qs: i made changes and tried it was reflecting, but was not able to respond.After adding config file it is responding.